# what is currently selected in chart in powerpoint

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I would like to check which item is selected in Chart in powerpoint. For e.g., If I have selected the Datalabels in chart in powerpoint then I want to print through macro that "Datalabels" is selected.

The below code is working in excel. But in powerpoint its giving a error.

Can anyone plsease help me out on this. thanks

Also is there any way to know that:
What is the series number that i have selected in chart in powerpoint?

```
MsgBox TypeName(Selection)
```

Comment: PPT has events like Excel, but refers to Presentations, Application & Slides. Not sure if you can add a change event based on click. Set up a class in the Class Modules and see what options you have...

Comment: `TypeName` works in PowerPoint in the same way. `Selection` it is extremely difficult to be defined. I mean chart elements selection. Otherwise, `ActiveWindow.Selection` returns only the main object (type)...

Comment: Is there any way to apply the formatting (e.g., text color to red) on SELECTED DATALABELS in chart in powerpoint?